# Lights Out Best-First Search/A* Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, a-star, heuristics, best-first-search

This is a homework assignment that I'm trying to develop more, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to go further.

The assignment is basically about solving [Lights Out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lights_Out_(game)) of different sizes using different approaches. I have developed a brute-force approach which works, but it takes a lot of time when the board size is big.

My problem comes when I'm trying to implement a best-first search or a A* approach to solve the game. I have to design a heuristic function for the game and this is where I'm having trouble. I don't have the slightest clue about what could be a good heuristic function in this case.

Having no prior experience in AI, I'd like to have some guidance/tips on how to develop a good heuristic function for the case of Lights Out.

Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

The heuristic only needs to give you a vague estimate of how many button presses at minimum are required.  One simple heuristic would be the `numberOfLightsRemaining/5`, since each press can at most turn off 5 lights.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That is indeed an interesting heuristic, but how would one judge it to be good or not?